# How to create a wrapper for SolidJS's setStore in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, solid-js

I have a SolidJS store defined:

```
const [store, setStore] = createStore<SomeComplexType>();
```

I need to run some code before every execution of `setStore`, so I would like to wrap it with my own function. Is there a way to do that that preserves all types and all overloads?

I've tried:

```
const setStore: SetStoreFunction<SomeComplexType> = (...args: Parameters<SetStoreFunction<SomeComplexType>>) => {
  setStore_(...args);
};
```

But I get an error:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

Comment: Does using a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with a [`// @ts-expect-error` directive comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments) (as shown in [this example](https://tsplay.dev/NdD6QN)) satisfy your needs?

Comment: @jsejcksn Yes, thank you for that. It solves the problem, though using error suppression to achieve this feels a bit off?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78209469/how-to-create-a-wrapper-for-solidjss-setstore-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment137884565_78209469) I agree… but every compiler does have limitations, and I suspect that there might not be a better alternative at present because of the complex overload signature (although I’d love to learn otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I heard is using `any[]` for the parameter type and casting `setStore` to `any`. It preserves types and doesn't require suppression via annotations.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZRtNAGjhgE8w04c0Y8CAxAVwDtkZgJm4BfOAMygQQcAEQBnCABtgAEwC0AKzEB6MfnQiA3AChtZCnHoQIcALyJ%20xgFxw1UYMwDmPHduSc1cANpqCxMTR06AC6ZijoWLjqaAA8RhAAfAAUSHzWogBGGFAiPACUru7MngG00QDqwDAAFgCifHxobDbUZQwsbBzMccYJYUkAdENg2RggYjYYzKRewXlmfQjacCgeUmgDkhCOSeKB0XAOAG4QANZoMnAA7lXVcCNQYzRoUBMixA9jYgXLcOgwjCgXCSpSClAwYjgU1IeUGw1G4x%203FcoIqt3qjTY2mUyhWePxBJWAD1sbiACrkcFcCAULgPNDMGpoMTASEiXZwaovSj4WxoSgASUZaEk0moxUoYkYjkczPYHmutxIlMOzDS2iAA)

```
import { createStore, type SetStoreFunction } from "solid-js/store";

type Foo = { foo: string };

const [store, setStore] = createStore<Foo>({ foo: "bar" });

const setStoreWithEffect: SetStoreFunction<Foo> = (...params: any[]) => {
  console.log("setStore invoked with parameters:", params);
  return (setStore as any)(...params);
};
```

Credits to Maciek50322.

Answer (score 1):

In order to preserve all of the overload information in the associated function type… you can [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a closure that executes your effect prior to invoking [`setStore`](https://docs.solidjs.com/concepts/stores#modifying-store-values) and returning its value.

The particular type in question has numerous complex overloads, and I don't know that it's possible to satisfy all of them as far as the TypeScript compiler can currently infer (although I'd love to learn otherwise). A [`// @ts-expect-error` directive comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments) can be used to suppress the compiler error diagnostic in the following example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZRtNAGjhgE8w04c0Y8CAxAVwDtkZgJm4BfOAMygQQcAEQBnCABtgAEwC0AKzEB6MfnQiA3AChtZCnHoQIcALyJ+xgFxw1UYMwDmPHduSc1cANpqCxMTR06AC6ZijoWLjqaAA8RhAAfAAUSHzWogBGGFAiPACUrsrKcAACMGJyaAAeFGyVUIJQNgByEPAYYmLAjswYGZJogGQEbh7wAbTRAOrAMAAWAKJ8fGhsNtQTDCxsHMxxxglhSQB0J2DZGCBiNl4YzKTBeWYHCNoAkO7MEgNHkhCOSeJAtE4A4AG4QADWaBkcAA7jNZnAzlALjQ0FAriJiMiLmICm90DBGFAuOMgmhjqdzpd8dxXGSpgjFss2NoinAOZyudy4AA9NnFAAq5EotzgEAoXGRaGYczQXTEogBcFm6Mo+FsaEoAElZWhJNJqJ9KGJGI5HPL2B44QiSCKQcw0togA)

```ts
import { createStore, type SetStoreFunction } from "solid-js/store";

type Foo = { foo: string };

const [store, setStore] = createStore<Foo>({ foo: "bar" });

// @ts-expect-error: Not assignable…
const setStoreWithEffect: SetStoreFunction<Foo> = (...params: [any]) => {
  console.log("setStore invoked with parameters:", params);
  return setStore(...params);
};
```

The IntelliSense quick info shows that the type information is preserved and the function can be used as expected:

[image: typescript intellisense quick info]

Quick info text in the screenshot above:

```
     setStoreWithEffect(k1: Part<Foo, "foo">, k2:
     Part<never, never>, k3: Part<never, never>, k4:
     Part<never, never>, k5: Part<never, never>, k6:
 ⌃   Part<never, never>, k7: Part<never, never>, setter:
1/9  (prevState: never, traversed: [never, never, never,
 ⌄   never, never, never, "foo"]) => never): void
```